# htaccess with multiple variables with a "dummy" directory

Tags: .htaccess, seo

**Information**

I am currently making my website more SEO friendly, therefor my index page accepts the following `$_GET['']` Requests.

`example.com/Variable1/staticword/Variable2`

`example.com/Variable1/staticword/Variable2/Variable3/`

`example.com/Variable1/staticword/Variable2/Variable3/Variable4`

`example.com/Variable1/staticword/Variable2/Variable4`

With Examples

`example.com/Arsenal/vs/Chelsea`

`example.com/Arsenal/vs/Chelsea/Emirates/`

`example.com/Arsenal/vs/Chelsea/Emirates/3048`

`example.com/Arsenal/vs/Chelsea/3048`

**Problem**

Is it possible to have a "dummy" directory, in this case `/vs/` in the url? or should I just have it as another variable so that users cant change it to anything they like and the website still work? such as `www.example.com/Arsenal/ANYTHINGUSERWANTSHERE/Chelsea`?

In both cases I am struggling to get a htaccess file to work for multiple variables, do I need multiple rewrite rules or just one that can accept them all even though they might not all present?

(Also regarding the last examples in both cases, the way I will allow users to skip the Variable3 / Stadium value is that the variable that could possibly be there aswell is the post id so I can perform a simple check to see if the $_GET is integer or not)

Thank you! And questions will be answered ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example.com/Variable1/staticword/Variable2/Variable4` is an url with a directory structure. You simply match the variable parts with a regex (`([^/]+)` for example) and the static part with just characters. These should all be internal rewrites. you have to match the most complex url structure first, and from there work your way down. You rewrite it to file that handles the request.

The easiest way is having seperate rules for each case, because in that case you don't have to make crazy regexes just to match all requests.

The following rules are untested, but hopefully should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/vs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /path/to/file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&place=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/vs/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /path/to/file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/vs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /path/to/file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&place=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/vs/([^/]+)/?$ /path/to/file.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

You might need to add the following RewriteCond(ition) before each of the rules to prevent it matching `/path/to/file.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/file\.php$
```

You can find more information [in the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Works perfect, and the way you made it regex to see if the 3rd variable is the id (number) or place (text) is genius and saves me doing it in PHP! Thank you!